# Place content in between paragraphs without images

Tags: php, html

I am using the following code to place some ad code inside my content .

```
<?php
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content);
$content = explode (' ', $content);
$halfway_mark = ceil(count($content) / 2);
$first_half_content = implode(' ', array_slice($content, 0, $halfway_mark));
$second_half_content = implode(' ', array_slice($content, $halfway_mark));
echo $first_half_content.'...';
echo ' YOUR ADS CODE';
echo $second_half_content;
?>
```

How can i modify this so that the 2 paragraphs (top and bottom) enclosing the ad code **should not be the one having images.** If the top or bottom paragraph has image then try for next 2 paragraphs.

**Example**: Correct Implementation on the right.

[image]

Comment: Is your problem that $item has images in it? Not sure if I follow.

Comment: Filter ```<img>``` tags from your items? I'm not sure what you want exactly.

Comment: Are you putting ads as images inside regular posts and then you want them to be in "the middle" of your content? If so, I think this is best done via CSS?

Comment: @Olavxxx the ads are scripts and the content is dynamic (wordpress post).

Comment: Sorry, I still dont 100% understand what you are trying to do.
You have your content that you wish to "split" and you dont want any images in the top or bottom part of the content you are splitting?

Where do you want those images?
Or is your problem just that you want to split your content in 2 and you are thinking about the fact that you might break the HTML (eg. split a paragraph, image, hr or whatever (a tag) in two?

Comment: @Olavxxx see the image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### preg_replace version

This code steps through every paragraph ignoring those that contain image tags. The `$pcount` variable is incremented for every paragraph found without an image, if an image is encountered however, `$pcount` is reset to zero. Once `$pcount` reaches the point where it would hit two, the advert markup is inserted just before that paragraph. This should leave the advert markup between two safe paragraphs. The advert markup variable is then nullified so only one advert is inserted.

The following code is just for set up and could be modified to split the content differently, you could also modify the regular expression that is used — just in case you are using double BRs or something else to delimit your paragraphs.

```
/// set our advert content
$advert = '<marquee>BUY THIS STUFF!!</marquee>' . "\n\n";
/// calculate mid point
$mpoint = floor(strlen($content) / 2);
/// modify back to the start of a paragraph
$mpoint = strripos($content, '<p', -$mpoint);
/// split html so we only work on second half
$first  = substr($content, 0, $mpoint);
$second = substr($content, $mpoint);
$pcount = 0;
$regexp = '/<p>.+?<\/p>/si';
```

The rest is the bulk of the code that runs the replacement. This could be modified to insert more than one advert, or to support more involved image checking.

```
$content = $first . preg_replace_callback($regexp, function($matches){
  global $pcount, $advert;
  if ( !$advert ) {
    $return = $matches[0];
  }
  else if ( stripos($matches[0], '<img ') !== FALSE ) {
    $return = $matches[0];
    $pcount = 0;
  }
  else if ( $pcount === 1 ) {
    $return = $advert . $matches[0];
    $advert = '';
  }
  else {
    $return = $matches[0];
    $pcount++;
  }
  return $return;
}, $second);
```

After this code has been executed the `$content` variable will contain the enhanced HTML.

#### PHP versions prior to 5.3

As your chosen testing area does not support PHP 5.3, and so does not support anonymous functions, you need to use a slightly modified and less succinct version; that makes use of a named function instead.

Also, in order to support content that may not actually leave space for the advert in it's second half I have modified the `$mpoint` so that it is calculated to be 80% from the end. This will have the effect of including more in the `$second` part — but will also mean your adverts will be generally placed higher up in the mark-up. This code has not had any fallback implemented into it, because your question does not mention what should happen in the event of failure.

```
$advert = '<marquee>BUY THIS STUFF!!</marquee>' . "\n\n";
$mpoint = floor(strlen($content) * 0.8);
$mpoint = strripos($content, '<p', -$mpoint);
$first  = substr($content, 0, $mpoint);
$second = substr($content, $mpoint);
$pcount = 0;
$regexp = '/<p>.+?<\/p>/si';

function replacement_callback($matches){
  global $pcount, $advert;
  if ( !$advert ) {
    $return = $matches[0];
  }
  else if ( stripos($matches[0], '<img ') !== FALSE ) {
    $return = $matches[0];
    $pcount = 0;
  }
  else if ( $pcount === 1 ) {
    $return = $advert . $matches[0];
    $advert = '';
  }
  else {
    $return = $matches[0];
    $pcount++;
  }
  return $return;
}

echo $first . preg_replace_callback($regexp, 'replacement_callback', $second);
```

Comment: @DebajyotiDas ~ what version of PHP are you running? You wont be able to support [anonymous callbacks](http://uk1.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) unless you are running 5.3 or above. If so, you should really upgrade, but it's not the end of the world you can probably use a named function instead. PS. the codepad link is a 404.. without knowing what errors you are getting I can't advise further as the code worked on my local set-up.

Comment: @DebajyotiDas Codepad is running PHP Version 5.2.5. Hence the reason for the error. The following should work for older versions of PHP ~ http://codepad.org/Fj56s6Rv

Comment: @DebajyotiDas ~ Two reasons. This first is I forgot to wrap the function name in a string in the last codepad -- Doh! -- and the other is that the above code only checks the second half of the content. Your test second half has no where it can place the ad so it fails. Here's a modified version which uses 80% of the remaining content, rather than the last half. http://codepad.org/yQ8RY1yI

Comment: Thanks lot for last time. Can you please modify it a bit so that it works not only for `<img ` but also `<h1>`, `<h2>`, `<h3>`, `<h4>` . Note: that the header tags are not inside `<p> ... </p>`

Comment: Rather we can actually ensure that ads are always surrounded by 2 paragraphs. That we header tags, video embeds etc are are not disturbing surrounding the ad

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
    <?php
  $ad_code = 'SOME SCRIPT HERE';

  // Your code.
  $content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content);

  // Split the content at the <p> tags.
  $content = explode ('<p>', $content);

  // Find the mid of the article.
  $content_length = count($content);
  $content_mid = floor($content_length / 2);

  // Save no image p's index.
  $last_no_image_p_index = NULL;

  // Loop beginning from the mid of the article to search for images.
  for ($i = $content_mid; $i < $content_length; $i++) {
    // If we do not find an image, let it go down.
    if (stripos($content[$i], '<img') === FALSE) {
      // In case we already have a last no image p, we check 
      // if it was the one right before this one, so we have
      // two p tags with no images in there.
      if ($last_no_image_p_index === ($i - 1)) {
        // We break here.
        break;
      }
      else {
        $last_no_image_p_index = $i;
      }
    }
  }

  // If no none image p tag was found, we use the last one.
  if (is_null($last_no_image_p_index)) {
    $last_no_image_p_index = ($content_length - 1);
  }

  // Add ad code here with trailing <p>, so the implode later will work correctly.
  $content = array_slice($content, $last_no_image_p_index, 0, $ad_code . '</p>');

  $content = implode('<p>', $content);
?>
```

It will try to find a place for the ad from the mid of your article and if none is found the ad is put to the end.

Regards
func0der

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work:

First explode the paragraphs, then you have to loop it and check if you find img inside them.
If you find it inside, you try the next.

Think of this as psuedo-code, since it's not tested. You will have to make a loop too, comments in the code :) Sorry if it contains bugs, it's written in Notepad.

```
<?php
$i = 0; // counter
$arrBoolImg = array(); // array for the paragraph booleans

$content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content);

$contents = str_replace ('<p>', '<explode><p>', $content); // here we add a custom tag, so we can explode
$contents = explode ('<explode>', $contents); // then explode it, so we can iterate the paragraphs

// fill array with boolean array returned
$arrBoolImg = hasImages($contents);
$halfway_mark = ceil(count($contents) / 2);

/* 
    TODO (by you):
    ---
    When you have $arrBoolImg filled, you can itarate through it.
    You then simply loop from the middle of the array $contents (plural), that is exploded from above.
    The startingpoing for your loop is the middle, the upper bounds is the +2 or what ever :-)
    Then you simply insert your magic.. And then glue it back together, as you did before.
    I think this will work. even though the code may have some bugs, since I wrote it in Notepad.
*/






function hasImages($contents) {
/* 
This function loops through the $contents array and checks if they have images in them
The return value, is an array with boolean values, so one can iterate through it.
*/
$arrRet = array(); // array for the paragraph booleans

if (count($content)>=1) {
    foreach ($contents as $v) { // iterate the content
    if (strpos($v, '<img') === false) { // did not find img
        $arrRet[$i] = false;
        }
        else {              // found img
        $arrRet[$i] = true; 
    }
    $i++;
    } // end for each loop
    return $arrRet;
} // end if count
} // end hasImages func

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

[This is just an idea, I don't have enough reputation to comment...]

After calling @Olavxxx's method and filling your boolean array you could just loop through that array in an alternating manner starting in the middle: Let's assume your array is 8 entries long. Calculating the middle using your method you get 4. So you check the combination of values 4 + 3, if that doesn't work, you check 4 + 5, after that 3 + 2, ...

So your loop looks somewhat like

```
$middle = ceil(count($content) / 2);
$i = 1;
while ($i <= $middle) {
  $j = $middle + (-1) ^ $i * $i;
  $k = $j + 1;

  if (!$hasImagesArray[$j] && !$hasImagesArray[$k])
    break; // position found

  $i++;
}
```

It's up to you to implement further constraints to make sure the add is not shown to far up or down in the article...

Please note that you need to take care of special cases like too short arrays too in order to prevent IndexOutOfBounds-Exceptions.