# Place Ads in between Text-Only Paragraphs

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using the following code to place some ad code inside my content .

```
<?php
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content);
$content = explode (' ', $content);
$halfway_mark = ceil(count($content) / 2);
$first_half_content = implode(' ', array_slice($content, 0, $halfway_mark));
$second_half_content = implode(' ', array_slice($content, $halfway_mark));
echo $first_half_content.'...';
echo ' YOUR ADS CODE';
echo $second_half_content;
?>
```

How can I modify this so that I can **place 2 ads** out at the same time in between text only paragraphs (both the `<p>...</p>` enclosing the ad should not have images or embedded videos).

I want to avoid jQuery.

*Example of my Usecase...*
[image: Example of my usecase]

- I want to insert 2 advert blocks in this article.
- I want the 1st ad block to be after the 1st paragraph. But any image in the 1st paragraph should be removed.
- For the 2nd ad it should be placed possible in the second half of the article in between text-only paragraph such that an ad code sandwitched between a good amount of text and is never very near to an embedded image or video etc.
- There should be at least 2 paragraphs between 2 ads

Comment: "place 3 ads equally spaced" i.e. 3 divs horizontally across?

Comment: @David - vertically, like 1para 2para AD 3para 4 para ....

Comment: Aren't you going to kill your site with so many ads. Just be careful if they are google adsense ads.

Comment: What if there is no para without image or video. There can be no. of use cases. What do you actually want to achieve

Comment: In content rich sites... thats not possible. And we have a use case where the 2nd if not 3rd should be placed at the end.

Comment: What do you mean by "But any image in the 1st paragraph should be removed"

Comment: @PieterGoosen means if the first para has an embeded image it shud be removed... only  words should be there in the 1st para. Similar to how wordpress generate excerpts.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is my approach to the question. Sorry for posting a bit late ( and missing the bounty :-( ), but it has been a hectic week, so I did everything in bits and pieces.

**QUICK RUNDOWN**

- I have not removed the attachments in the first paragraph. I don't really see why content must be vandalized for the sake of an ad
- I have done quite a lot of checks in my code to try and make sure that ads are only inserted in between text only paragraphs. Text only paragraphs are taken to be paragraphs that does not contain img, li and ul tags
- I have documented each block of code properly, so you can easily work through each section. I have also added `todo` doc blocks which you need to attend to, if necessary
- I have used `wptexturize` to apply p tags to `the_content`. Each double line break constitutes a paragraph
- Modify and use this code as you see fit. I have tested it, so it is bug free on my side.

Here is the code. Hope this works for you as expected. *PS! All of this goes into your functions.php. No need for any other code or mods to your template files

```
<?php
add_filter( 'the_content', 'so_25888630_ad_between_paragraphs' );

function so_25888630_ad_between_paragraphs($content){
    /**-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
     *
     *  @author       Pieter Goosen <http://stackoverflow.com/users/1908141/pieter-goosen>
     *  @return       Ads in between $content
     *  @link         http://stackoverflow.com/q/25888630/1908141
     * 
     *  Special thanks to the following answers on my questions that helped me to
     *  to achieve this
     *     - http://stackoverflow.com/a/26032282/1908141
     *     - http://stackoverflow.com/a/25988355/1908141
     *     - http://stackoverflow.com/a/26010955/1908141
     *     - http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/162787/31545
     *
    *------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/ 
    if( in_the_loop() ){ //Simply make sure that these changes effect the main query only

        /**-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
         *
         *  wptexturize is applied to the $content. This inserts p tags that will help to  
         *  split the text into paragraphs. The text is split into paragraphs after each
         *  closing p tag. Remember, each double break constitutes a paragraph.
         *  
         *  @todo If you really need to delete the attachments in paragraph one, you want
         *        to do it here before you start your foreach loop
         *
        *------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/ 
        $closing_p = '</p>';
        $paragraphs = explode( $closing_p, wptexturize($content) );

        /**-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
         *
         *  The amount of paragraphs is counted to determine add frequency. If there are
         *  less than four paragraphs, only one ad will be placed. If the paragraph count
         *  is more than 4, the text is split into two sections, $first and $second according
         *  to the midpoint of the text. $totals will either contain the full text (if 
         *  paragraph count is less than 4) or an array of the two separate sections of
         *  text
         *
         *  @todo Set paragraph count to suite your needs
         *
        *------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/ 
        $count = count( $paragraphs );
        if( 4 >= $count ) {
            $totals = array( $paragraphs ); 
        }else{
            $midpoint = floor($count / 2);
            $first = array_slice($paragraphs, 0, $midpoint );
            if( $count%2 == 1 ) {
                $second = array_slice( $paragraphs, $midpoint, $midpoint, true );
            }else{
                $second = array_slice( $paragraphs, $midpoint, $midpoint-1, true );
            }
            $totals = array( $first, $second );
        }

        $new_paras = array();   
        foreach ( $totals as $key_total=>$total ) {
            /**-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
             *
             *  This is where all the important stuff happens
             *  The first thing that is done is a work count on every paragraph
             *  Each paragraph is is also checked if the following tags, a, li and ul exists
             *  If any of the above tags are found or the text count is less than 10, 0 is 
             *  returned for this paragraph. ($p will hold these values for later checking)
             *  If none of the above conditions are true, 1 will be returned. 1 will represent
             *  paragraphs that qualify for add insertion, and these will determine where an ad 
             *  will go
             *  returned for this paragraph. ($p will hold these values for later checking)
             *
             *  @todo You can delete or add rules here to your liking
             *
            *------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/ 
            $p = array();
            foreach ( $total as $key_paras=>$paragraph ) {
                $word_count = count(explode(' ', $paragraph));
                if( preg_match( '~<(?:img|ul|li)[ >]~', $paragraph ) || $word_count < 10 ) {  
                    $p[$key_paras] = 0; 
                }else{
                    $p[$key_paras] = 1; 
                }   
            }

            /**-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
             *
             *  Return a position where an add will be inserted
             *  This code checks if there are two adjacent 1's, and then return the second key
             *  The ad will be inserted between these keys
             *  If there are no two adjacent 1's, "no_ad" is returned into array $m
             *  This means that no ad will be inserted in that section
             *
            *------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/ 
            $m = array();
            foreach ( $p as $key=>$value ) {
                if( 1 === $value && array_key_exists( $key-1, $p ) && $p[$key] === $p[$key-1] && !$m){
                    $m[] = $key;
                }elseif( !array_key_exists( $key+1, $p ) && !$m ) {
                    $m[] = 'no-ad';
                }
            } 

            /**-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
             *
             *  Use two different ads, one for each section
             *  Only ad1 is displayed if there is less than 4 paragraphs
             *
             *  @todo Replace "PLACE YOUR ADD NO 1 HERE" with your add or code. Leave p tags
             *  @todo I will try to insert widgets here to make it dynamic
             *
            *------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/ 
            if( $key_total == 0 ){
                $ad = array( 'ad1' => '<p>PLACE YOUR ADD NO 1 HERE</p>' );
            }else{
                $ad = array( 'ad2' => '<p>PLACE YOUR ADD NO 2 HERE</p>' );
            }

            /**-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
             *
             *  This code loops through all the paragraphs and checks each key against $mail
             *  and $key_para
             *  Each paragraph is returned to an array called $new_paras. $new_paras will
             *  hold the new content that will be passed to $content.
             *  If a key matches the value of $m (which holds the array key of the position
             *  where an ad should be inserted) an add is inserted. If $m holds a value of
             *  'no_ad', no ad will be inserted
             *
            *------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/ 
            foreach ( $total as $key_para=>$para ) {
                if( !in_array( 'no_ad', $m ) && $key_para === $m[0] ){
                    $new_paras[key($ad)] = $ad[key($ad)];
                    $new_paras[$key_para] = $para;
                }else{
                    $new_paras[$key_para] = $para;
                }
            }
        }

        /**-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
         *
         *  $content should be a string, not an array. $new_paras is an array, which will
         *  not work. $new_paras are converted to a string with implode, and then passed
         *  to $content which will be our new content
         *
        *------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/ 
        $content =  implode( ' ', $new_paras );
    }
    return $content;
}
```

**EDIT**

From your comments:

- You should use the following code to debug `<pre><?php var_dump($NAME_OF_VARIABLE); ?></pre>`. For your first issue, I will use `?><pre><?php var_dump($paragraphs); ?></pre><?php` just after this line `$paragraphs = explode( $closing_p, wpautop($content) );` to exactly see how the content is split up.  This will give you an idea if your content is being split up correctly.
- Also use `?><pre><?php var_dump($p); ?></pre><?php` just after this line `$p = array();` to inspect what value is given to a specific paragraph. Remember, paragraphs with img, li and ul tags should have a `0`, also paragraphs with less than 10 words. The rest should have a 1
- *EDIT* -> Issue with stripped paragraphs is resolved. Thanks for pointing that flaw out to me. Never realized this. I have updated the code, so just simply copy and paste it

**EDIT 2**

Please note, you cannot test your code with the online tool you are using. This is not a true reflection of of what is output by `the_content()`. The output that you see using your online tool is filtered and marked up before being send to the screen as `the_content()`. If you inspect your output with a browser like google chrome, you will see that p tags are correctly applied.

I have also changed the a tag with image tag in the code

Comment: OMG, this works like a charm. THANKS a ton, since I will be updating my site with this. Tried very hard to fail this in many ways but failed. Solid code. All requirements passed. :) My respect...You deseve a bounty. I will remember this and award you one when I have more of my own.

Comment: Note: exploding with `</p>` creates output without the `</p>`. So I am using `$paragraphs = preg_split("/(?=<\/p>)/", $content, null, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);` which seems to works fine.

Answer (score 3):

with the sample code you have given me this is the best i can do, there were far too many images in there, you would need a genius to figure out the logic required for your requirements, but try it out it might not be too far off. You'll need php 5.5 for this.

**a couple of points to note:**
1. it identifies paragraphs as being wrapped in p elements, not as in visual paragraphs.
 
2. if p elements exist inside other elements, it will also recognise them as paragraphs. The first ad is a example of this. Avoid using p inside blockquotes, lists, etc, its not necessary, use spans, divs for text instead.
3. I have commented a line calling a function in __construct, uncomment this to insert the 2nd image. This actually works well but your content has a lot of p elements with sentances split over a number of p's, this is unlikely to be a factor in actual content. 
4. It searches for images in para 1 + para 2 and removes them.

```
$content = apply_filters('the_content', get_the_content() ); 

    class adinsert {


    var $content;
    var $paragraphs;    
    var $ad_pos1=2;
    var $ad_pos2;
    var $ad_pos3;
    var $ad= '<h1>ad position here</h1>';

public function __construct($content) {

    if(!$content)
        return $content;

    $this->set_content($content);

    $this->paragrapherize(2);
    $this->paragraph_numbers();
    $this->get_first_pos();
    $this->paragrapherize();
    $this->paragraph_numbers();
    $this->find_images();
    $this->find_ad_pos(); 
    $this->insert_ads();

}


public function echo_content(){
    echo $this->content;
}

private function insert_ads() {

    if($this->ad_pos2 && $this->ad_pos2 != 'end'):
        $posb= $this->ad_pos2;
        $this->content=substr_replace($this->content,$this->ad,$posb ,0);
    else:
        $this->content.= $this->ad;    
    endif;

    //comment the below line to remove last image insertion 
    $this->content.= $this->ad;
}

private function get_first_pos() {

    $i=0;

    foreach($this->paragraphs as $key=>$data):
        if($i==0):

            $length= $data['end']-$data['start'];
            $string= substr($this->content, $data['start'],$length);    
            $newkey= $key+1;
            $lengthb= $this->paragraphs[$newkey]['end']-$this->paragraphs[$newkey]['start'];
            $stringb= substr($this->content, $this->paragraphs[$newkey]['start'],$lengthb);

            $wcount= count(explode(' ', $string));

            if( preg_match('/(<img[^>]+>)/i', $string, $image) ):
                    $newstring=preg_replace('/(<img[^>]+>)/i', '', $string);

                        if($wcount>10):
                            $newstring.=$this->ad;
                            $this->ad_pos1=1;       
                            $this->content=str_replace($string,$newstring,$this->content);
                        endif;
            else:
                        if($wcount>10) :
                            $newstring=$string.$this->ad;
                            echo $newstring;
                            $this->ad_pos1=1;
                            //$this->content=str_replace($string,$newstring,$this->content);
                            $this->content= preg_replace('~'.$string.'~', $newstring, $this->content, 1);
                        endif;
            endif;

            if( preg_match('/(<img[^>]+>)/i', $stringb, $imageb) ):
                        $newstringb=preg_replace('/(<img[^>]+>)/i', '', $stringb);  
                        if($wcount<10) :
                        $newstringb.=$this->ad;
                        $this->ad_pos1=2;
                        $this->content=str_replace($stringb,$newstringb,$this->content);
                        endif;
            else:
                        if($wcount<10) :
                            $newstring=$stringb.$this->ad;
                            $this->ad_pos1=2;
                            $this->content=str_replace($stringb,$newstringb,$this->content);
                        endif;
            endif;

        else:
            break;
        endif;
        $i++;       
    endforeach;
}


private function find_ad_pos() {

    $remainder_images= $this->paragraph_count;
    if($remainder_images < $this->ad_pos1 + 3):
        $this->ad_pos2='end';
    else:   

        foreach($this->paragraphs as $key=>$data):
            $p[]=$key;
        endforeach;

        unset($p[0]);
        unset($p[1]);

        $startpos= $this->ad_pos1 + 2;
        $possible_ad_positions= $remainder_images - $startpos;
    //figure out half way
        if($remainder_images < 3): //use end pos
            $pos1= $startpos;
            $pos1=$this->getclosestkey($pos1, $p);
        else: // dont use end pos
            $pos1=  ($remainder_images/2)-1;
            $pos1= $this->getclosestkey($pos1, $p);
        endif;
        $this->ad_pos2= $this->paragraphs[$pos1]['end'];
    endif;
}


private function getclosestkey($key, $keys) {
    $close= 0;
    foreach($keys as $item): //4>4
        if($close == null || $key - $close > $item - $key ) :
          $close = $item;
        endif;
    endforeach;
    return $close;
}



private function find_images() {

    foreach($this->paragraphs as $item=>$key):
        $length= $key['end']-$key['start'];
        $string= substr($this->content, $key['start'],$length);
        if(strpos($string,'src')!==false && $item !=0 && $item !=1):
            //unset the number, find start in paragraphs array + 1 after
            unset($this->paragraphs[$item]);
            $nextitem= $item+1;
            $previtem= $item-1;
            unset($this->paragraphs[$nextitem]);
            unset($this->paragraphs[$previtem]);
        endif;          
    endforeach;

}





private function paragraph_numbers() {

    $i=1;
    foreach($this->paragraphs as $item):
        $i++;
    endforeach; 
    $this->paragraph_count=$i;
}

private function paragrapherize($limit=0) {

    $current_pos=0;
    $i=0;

    while( strpos($this->content, '<p', $current_pos) !== false ):

    if($limit && $i==$limit)
        break;

    if($i==105) {
        break;
    }
        if($i!=0) {
            $current_pos++; 
        }


        $paragraph[$i]['start']=strpos($this->content, '<p', $current_pos);//1

    //looking for the next time a /p follows a /p so is less than the next position of p

    $nextp= strpos($this->content, '<p', $paragraph[$i]['start']+1); //14 failing on next???
    $nextendp= strpos($this->content, '</p>', $current_pos);//22

    if($nextp>$nextendp)://NO
        $paragraph[$i]['end']=$nextendp;
        if( ($nextendp - $paragraph[$i]['start']) < 80 ):
            unset($paragraph[$i]);
        endif;

        $current_pos= $nextendp;
        $i++;   
    else:   

    $startipos = $nextendp;

        $b=0;                                           
        do {
            if($b==100){
               break;
            }

            $nextp= strpos($this->content, '<p', $startipos); //230
            $nextendp= strpos($this->content, '</p>', $startipos+1);//224


            if($nextp>$nextendp) {

                $paragraph[$i]['end']=$nextendp;
                $current_pos= $nextendp;

                $i++;
            } else {
                $startipos = $nextendp+1;
            }
            $b++;

        } while ($nextp < $nextendp );
    endif;
        endwhile;
        $this->paragraphs= $paragraph;
    }

    public function set_content($content) {
        $this->content= $content;
    }

}

$newcontent= new adinsert($content);
```

then where you want to output your content

```
 <?php echo $newcontent->echo_content(); ?>
```

Comment: Yes it worked... :) 1. But the 3rd ad is getting placed just before an image https://eval.in/private/2f5c211b9788c4  2. And its also removing existing div blocks. 3. There should be atleast 2 paragraphs between 2 ads

Comment: its also removing existing non p blocks like `div` `table` etc

Comment: can you paste the actual html content somewhere so i can get a idea of typical output? It is designed to use p as the outer wrapper as that is what i assumed each block consists of. Also have a look at the if else block using `$ad_avail_positions` that decides when the ads are placed...how many paragraphs would there normally be? If its a very wide range of variance, the function tends to get a bit bloated unless you can use something simple like if ad in this block, put the next ad 2 blocks away if no image, or if image, skip to next available, etc!

Comment: You can see what I have defined for `$content` here https://eval.in/private/2f5c211b9788c4    Note: Tables, lists don't form inside of p block in html... they are outside. I think we can include these common markups in getElementsByTagName. what do you think

Comment: Common tags outside <p> are <h1>, <table>, <ul>, <ol>, <blockquote>

Comment: we can pull all the tags with get elements by tagname, thats no problem but do you still only want the ads to appear only after paragraphs or after lists etc? Ill have a look at this tomorrow and get it done. but feel free to have a tinker with it as well :)

Comment: The preference should be to consider lists tables p etc as blocks. But the best case for the ad to be injected between 2 paragraphs like `..END</p> here <p>START..`

Comment: i updated what i can, the problem is you are giving me content with a lot of images ..... hard to figure out a pattern i can use. Nway its as close as anyone can get i believe.

Comment: This is so great ... :) Genius... Here is a test https://eval.in/private/a72f3efc0e2d72 but the ad got added 5 times. not sure why

Comment: Works great... But fails if the no. of paragraps is of lesser number or 1 or 2. In some cases ads are place next to each other, not keeping a paragrph in between. Major issue. the ads are injected anywhere inside the paragraph and not at the end...

Comment: can you post actual content where that happens?...the code finds the outer <p> tags and  and inserts the ad after the closing p tag.

Comment: Its too risky.. I am really sorry can I change the use case where only 2 ads placed, the 1st one after the 1st paragraph and 2nd one after the article half point in-between text-only paragraphs. There is an already existing solution for the 2nd part... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22091690 only need to combine adding the 1st ad code after the 1st para and stripping away any image in the first para. Since I can anyways place the 3rd one at the end manywally.

Comment: theres no risk as all, if your html is online anyone can view it. 2 ads is no problem either but you were saying 2 ads got placed together and inside <p> tags? Ill have a look later!

Comment: For eg: in this type of content the server hangs up... no response. http://debajyotidas.com/1173/markup-title-with-markup/

Comment: hmm i think it will perform much better with actual content for example this code http://www.testserverdavideec.mx.nf/samppe/ is full of p tags for every sentance. At the moment inbetween 2 paragraphs  could be in a blockquote, splitting a word, etc. The way wordpress content is normally formatted uses a lot less p's unless you add them yourself! But ill change it to what you said earlier!

Comment: ok updated that check the notes above for a few comments about the way it works.

Comment: Example : http://debajyotidas.com/358/post-format-standard/ The 2nd  block is getting plaed in the end. And if we are folling the new req, where only 2 ads will be place... the 2nd shud never be placed at end...since I am  placin it manually.

Comment: thats the third block not the second block! did you uncomment the line in __construct?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61661/discussion-on-answer-by-david-place-ads-in-between-text-only-paragraphs).

Comment: @David plz reply in the chat.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function echo_content() on a non-object in

Comment: Ok great. Before I accept the answer.. can you just make sure the code is safe. Any chances of an error etc.

Comment: i added something there to ensure no errors are possible (only if content was missing!)

Comment: The previous one was working better since now (latest one). places the 2nd ad at the end, along with the 3rd.

Comment: i commented out the code that does that. It was looking for at least 3 substanical paragraphs after the 1st ad pos to see if it should post. if you want it back in uncomment and play with the 1st if statement in it.

Comment: So with the code commented out, the 2nd will be places only if a suitable location is found and not at the end since the 3rd is always added in the end right?

Comment: no, it will always place the ad at the next suitable location but you may have a situation where it places the ad on the second last para or last as per your orig instruction

Comment: Why 4 ads are getting placed http://debajyotidas.com/1174/title-with-special-characters/ ?

Comment: its because you have repeated 1 full paragraph (see the 1st paragraph appears exactly later on?). The function looks to replace the text of the original paragraph with the new text but it will do it for every time it sees that paragraph. I've changed str replace to preg replace the 1st occurance it finds.

Comment: Can you please check once, becoz its duplicating the 1st para with ads in all cases.

Answer (score 2):

This is one solution. It's not fully programmatic, but I've done it before and it will work. Basically, use a "shortcode". The problem with doing it fully programatically is that there's no nice way of finding if the flow of an article with inline images, videos, etc. would cause the ad placements to look really bad. Instead, set up your CMS with a shortcode so that editors can place ads in an optimal place in the article.

E.g.

```
<p>Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet short ribs tenderloin venison pastrami meatloaf kevin, shoulder meatball landjaeger pork corned beef turkey salami frankfurter jerky. Pork loin bresaola porchetta strip steak meatball t-bone andouille chuck chicken shankle shank tongue. Hamburger flank kevin short ribs. Pork loin landjaeger frankfurter corned beef, fatback salami short loin ground round biltong.</p>

[ad_block]

<p>Pastrami jerky drumstick swine ribeye strip steak pork belly kevin tail rump pancetta capicola. Meatloaf doner porchetta, rump tenderloin t-bone biltong pork belly. Porchetta boudin ham ribeye frankfurter flank short loin, drumstick pork loin filet mignon chuck fatback. Strip steak jowl capicola ham hock turducken biltong ground round filet mignon venison prosciutto chuck pork. Venison ribeye fatback kielbasa, ball tip turducken capicola drumstick sausage pancetta boudin turkey ham strip steak corned beef.</p>
```

Then, using PHP's `str_replace` you can simply swap out the ad_block shortcode with your HTML for your ads.

E.g.

```
echo str_replace('[ad_block]', $ad_block_html, $content);
```

Comment: Completely agree... But it makes sense only for fairly new sites. Nightmare for an already large site, single handlely managed.

Comment: Thanks for the bacon... sorry I didn't solve the whole problem! :)

Answer (score 2):

I did some rework and this is what I finally got.
Feel free to test and give me some feedback.

```
class Advertiser
{
    /**
     * All advertises to place
     *
     * @access  private
     * @var     array
     */
    private $ads        = array();

    /**
     * The position behind the </p> element nearest to the center
     *
     * @access  private
     * @var     int
     */
    private $center     = null;

    /**
     * The content to parse
     *
     * @access  private
     * @var     string
     */
    private $content    = null;

    /**
     * Constructor method
     *
     * @access  public
     * @param   string  $content    the content to parse (optional)
     * @param   array   $ads        all advertises to place (optional)
     * @return  object              itself as object
     */
    public function __construct ($content = null, $ads = array())
    {
        if (count($ads)) $this->ads = $ads;
        if ($content) $this->setContent($content);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Calculates and sets the position behind the </p> element nearest to the center
     *
     * @access  public
     * @return  object              the position behind the </p> element nearest to the center
     */
    public function calcCenter ()
    {
        $content = $this->content;

        if (!$content) return $this;

        $center = ceil(strlen($content)/2);

        $rlpos  = strripos(substr($content, 0, $center), '</p>');
        $rrpos  = stripos($content, '</p>', $center);

        $this->center = 4 + ($center-$rlpos <= $rrpos-$center ? $rlpos : $rrpos);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Places the first ad
     *
     * @access  public
     * @param   string  $ad optional; if not specified, take the internally setted ad
     * @return  object      itself as object
     */
    public function placeFirstAd ($ad = null)
    {
        $ad = $ad ? $ad : $this->ads[0];
        $content = $this->content;

        if (!$content || !$ad) return $this;

        // the position before and after the first paragraph
        $pos1 = strpos($content, '<p');
        $pos2 = strpos($content, '</p>') + 4;

        // place ad
        $content = substr($content, 0, $pos2) . $ad . substr($content, $pos2);

        // strip images
        $content = substr($content, 0, $pos1) . preg_replace('#<img(?:\s.*?)?/?>#i', '', substr($content, $pos1, $pos2)) . substr($content, $pos2);

        $this->content = $content;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Places the second ad
     *
     * @access  public
     * @param   string  $ad optional; if not specified, take the internally set ad
     * @return  object      itself as object
     */
    public function placeSecondAd ($ad = null)
    {
        $ad = $ad ? $ad : $this->ads[1];
        $content = $this->content;

        if (!$content || !$ad) return $this;

        $center = $this->center;

        // place ad
        $content = substr($content, 0, $center) . $ad . substr($content, $center);

        $this->content = $content;

        return $this;
    }

    /* Getters */

    /**
     * Gets the content in it's current state
     *
     * @access  public
     * @return  string  the content in it's current state
     */
    public function getContent ()
    {
        return $this->content;
    }

    /* Setters */

    /**
     * Sets the content
     *
     * @access  public
     * @param   string  $content    the content to parse
     * @return  object              itself as object
     */
    public function setContent ($content)
    {
        $this->content = $content;

        $this->calcCenter();

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the first ad
     *
     * @access  public
     * @param   string  $ad the ad
     * @return  object      itself as object
     */
    public function setFirstAd ($ad)
    {
        if ($ad) $this->ad[0] = $ad;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the second ad
     *
     * @access  public
     * @param   string  $ad the ad
     * @return  object      itself as object
     */
    public function setSecondAd ($ad)
    {
        if ($ad) $this->ad[1] = $ad;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
$first_ad   = 'bacon';
$second_ad  = 'ham';

$content    = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content);

$advertiser = new Advertiser($content);

$advertiser->placeFirstAd($first_ad);
//$advertiser-> placeSecondAd($second_ad);

$advertised_content = $advertiser->getContent();
```

You can comment the placeSecondAd() out or replace it with your working function.

Comment: where are you adding the 1st ad

Comment: Warning: preg_match_all(): Unknown modifier 'p' in

Comment: the 2nd ad shud be placed in between paragraphs which doesn't have any images. see the pic. Thanks

Comment: @DebajyotiDas Sorry, I forgot to add the first ad... :D I also corrected the typo in the expression, so it should hopefully work now. I programmed everything out of my head as I have no PHP installed, so, unfortunately, I can't test it. Please inform me of any other errors.

Comment: Thanks... Note: the 2nd ad shud be placed in between paragraphs which doesn't have any images. see the pic in question.

Comment: @DebajyotiDas Yea, images will only be replaced in the first paragraph. :)

Comment: I can see that, but I am talking for the 2nd ad... it shud be placed only betwwen paragraphs which doesn't have any images in it. Like if para 2, para3 has images and para4 and para5 doesn't.. then 2nd ad will be placed after para4

Comment: @DebajyotiDas What should happen if there are only 5 paragraphs and only para5 has no images? Also: what if every second para got an image?

Comment: Its rare. but in that case ad shuldn't be place... case: either place ad between text-only paras or don't place at all

Comment: It removes all non-paragraph tags like... `table`, `h1, h2`, `div`, `embed` etc @Icefyre

Comment: @DebajyotiDas Yes, the script only fetches paragraphs. Everything inside won't be touched (except for images in the first paragraph), but everything outside will be skipped, as I thought that's how it's designed. Could you maybe provide an all-cases-included example?

Comment: There is a solution for the 2nd part of my req. http://stackoverflow.com/a/22159723/1278540 I just need to put the 1st ad after the 1st para stripping images. and then 2nd ad in the way done in that question

Comment: @DebajyotiDas I did some changes. Maybe you want to have another look on it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a smart way:

```
$content = "<p>A</p><p>B</p><p>C</p><p>D</p>";
$pos = 2;
$content = preg_replace('/<p>/', '<helper>', $content, $pos + 1); //<helper>A</p><helper>B</p><helper>C</p><p>D</p>
$content = preg_replace('/<helper>/', '<p>', $content, $pos);     //<p>A</p><p>B</p><helper>C</p><p>D</p>
$content = str_replace("<helper>", "<p>ad</p><p>", $content);     //<p>A</p><p>B</p><p>ad</p><p>C</p><p>D</p>
```

Here is a complete function:

```
function insertAd($content, $ad, $pos = 0){
  // $pos = 0 means randomly position in the content
  $count = substr_count($content, "<p>");
  if($count == 0  or $count <= $pos){
    return $content;
  }
  else{
    if($pos == 0){
      $pos = rand (1, $count - 1);
    }
    $content = preg_replace('/<p>/', '<helper>', $content, $pos + 1);
    $content = preg_replace('/<helper>/', '<p>', $content, $pos);
    $content = str_replace('<helper>', $ad . "\n<p>", $content);
    return $content;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is an idea to move you in (possibly) a direction closer to the fully programmatic way you're asking...

Use a HTML DOM parser like http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ to parse each article. Using this, you should theoretically be able to pick out all the paragraph tags, and then insert the ad blocks in between the right ones based on your math.

```
$html = str_get_html($content);
$paragraphs_arr = $html->find('p'); //Returns all paragraphs
$halfway_mark = ceil(count($paragraphs_arr) / 2);

$halfway_paragraph = $paragraphs_arr[$halfway_mark];

// Somewhere here now you just have to figure out how to inject the ad right after the halfway paragraph.

E.g.
$p_content = $halfway_paragraph->innertext();
$p_content = $p_content."</p><p><!-- Ad --></p>"; // Force close the tag as we're in the innertext.
$halfway_paragraph->innertext($p_content);
```

Does that get a bit closer to what you're trying to do?

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
 strip_tags('contnet','like <p>');
```

Comment: At this answers the question ***how***

Answer (score -2):

```
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content);
// $middle will mark the center of the $content based on number of characters and is aware of words and will therefor mark the middle to the nearest space. +1 is added to then remove the whitespace at the end of the string.
$middle = strrpos(substr($content, 0, floor(strlen($content) / 2)), ' ') + 1;
// $first_half will substring the text to the first half based on where $middle says to split it
$first_half= substr($text, 0, $middle);
// $second_half substrings the text to the seconf half based on where $first_half is split.
$second_half= substr($text, $middle);
echo $first_half.'...';
echo ' YOUR ADS CODE';
echo $second_half;
```

Comment: I think it would be more helpful for the OP and further visitors, when you add some explaination to your intension.

Comment: Where are you checking for embedded images or videos ?