# Returning keys if 3 adjacent values match

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array

```
[true, false, false, true, true, false, false, true, true, true, false, false]
```

I know how to get midpoint and use either `ceil()` or `floor()` to get the nearest integer value and how to check whether the value before and after this midpoint have the same value as my midpoint.

My problem is, I need three `true` values next to each other for my condition to return `true`. In this example, using midpoint and the values adjacent to it will return `false`. Midpoint is my prefered position here as I need to do something there if my condition returns `true`. When this however returns `false`, I need to get any other position where there are three `true` values next to each other. I need to get the keys as I need the key to detemine the midpoint as I need to insert a value there.

So from my example, I need key number 7, 8 and 9 to be returned, not the values of these keys

Any suggestions to achieve this?

Comment: can you give other example

Comment: Meaning what, what do I need to clear up? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure u want this or not. Anyway plz try the below code

```
$a = array(true, false, false, true, true, false, false, true, true, true, false, false);
for ($i=0;$i<(sizeof($a)-1);$i++)
{
    if($i!=0&&$i!=(sizeof($a)-1))
    {
        if($a[$i-1]==$a[$i])
        {
            if($a[$i]==$a[$i+1])
            {
                echo ($i-1).','.$i.','.($i+1).'<br>';
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I can't test it right now. Will quickly test this afternoon. Must still test the other answer as well :-). Will keep you up to date. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Convert the array to a string containing '1' and '0' and then search for '111':

```
$a = [true, false, false, true, true, false, false, true, true, true, false, false];

$b = array_map(function ($item) {
    return $item ? 1 : 0;
}, $a);

$joined = implode('', $b);
if (($pos = strpos($joined, '111')) !== false) {
    printf("Your positions are %d, %d and %d\n", $pos, $pos +1, $pos + 2);
} else {
    printf("Did not found 3 consecutive 'true'");
}
```

Comment: I actually did not think about doing it this way. Will test this afternoon. +1 for your idea