# Finding attachement, h/li/ul tags

Tags: php, regex

I need to check (not necessarily return) if a certain text contains any type of attachment, h tags, li tags or ul tags. My knowledge of regex is really poor. I have found the following pieces of code on this site

```
preg_match_all('/<a\s[^>]*href=([\"\']??)([^\" >]*?)\\1[^>]*>(.*)<\/a>/siU', $text, $matches);
```

work perfectly and return all attachments attached to a text. How do I also add h/li/ul tags to this?

I respect the one question per post restriction, but is the the only way to just check for an occurrence of the above. I know functions like `strpos` and `stripos()`, but it seems it only accepts one `haystack`

**EDIT**

Here is an example of the text. *Sorry for the language, my site is in Afrikaans*. What I need to do is, I need to know if the text contains attachments, h tags, li tags or ul tags

```
Vandat ek my gedagtes gekry het kan ek onthou dat my pa dol was oor sy gestopte soetrissies. Dit was vir my pa 'n welverdiende lekkerny wat beter was as 'n koningsmaal, en so was dit, as pa 'n geldjie en tyd gehad het, dan is ons seuns en ma beloon met lekkers en pa met gevulde soetrissies.

<a href="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/AfrikaansHaka_d9e5_w_2.3gp">AfrikaansHaka_d9e5_w_2</a>

Hoe presies my pa dit gemaak het kan ek nie onthou nie, daarvoor is my gedagtes te min, lol. Ek kan wel onthou van die rys en maalvleis. Ek is nie rerig 'n groot ryseter nie, seker omdat ek nie Chinees is nie. So ek het gekyk na alternatiewe vir rys, en koeskoes was die antwoord. Koeskoes is een van die voedsels wat baie min gebruik word en baie min mense ken dit. Koeskoes is gaar gedroogte pasta korrels en lyk amper soos growwe braaipap meel. Dit maak koeskoes ook een van die vinnigste en lekkerste kosse om voor te berei, en ek sal julle wys in hierdie lekker resep vir my eie gevulde soetrissies.

<span style="text-decoration: underline;"><strong>Bestandele:</strong></span>
<ul>
    <li>4 tot 6 Soetrissies, koppe afgesny en pitte en stronke verwyder</li>
    <li>Gerasperde kaas</li>
    <li>Tamatiesous of soet rissiesous</li>
    <li>Fyngekapte rissie (opsioneel)</li>
    <li>Fyngekapte cilantro vir garnering</li>
</ul>
<h3>Koeskoes (Couscous):</h3>
```

Comment: An example would be better.

Comment: Add sample text. Sorry for the language, but my site is in Afrikaans, but the important part is the tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since its only a check, you don't need to use preg_match_all, preg_match should suffice:

```
if (preg_match('~<(?:a|h[1-6]|ul|li)[ >]~i', $text)) { ...
```

Note: this way should return an unexpected result if one of these tags is enclosed in an html comment, or in a javascript string.

Comment: It is just normal text, so this should do just fine