# Add key/value pair in between two pairs in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have been looking and thinking, but can't come up with a viable solution to this problem.

I have an array with sequencial numerical keys

*Example:*

```
Array
 (
    [0] => value 0
    [1] => value 1
    [2] => value 2
    [3] => value 3
)
```

I need to add a new key/value pair in between two specific keys in my array.

*Example:*

I need to add `[a] => value a` between keys `1` and `2` like

```
Array
 (
    [0] => value 0
    [1] => value 1
    [a] => value a
    [2] => value 2
    [3] => value 3
)
```

What I already though of doing, but seems the long way around

- slicing my array in two, add my key/value pair to the back of slice one, and recombine my 2 slices into a single array
- somehow advancing each key by one after key `1` modifying my new key/value pair to `[2] => value a`, the add it to the back of the array, and then resort my array

Any suggestions to a quick clean way to achieve this

Comment: option 1 seems okay, slice, merge, merge, the only problem i see is when there is a collision

Comment: No, I will make sure to keep the key unique in my new key/value pair

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont know why you will do it ...

```
    $array = array(0=>0,1=>1,2=>2,3=>3);

    $add = array('a'=>'a');

    $before_key = 2;

    $new_array = array();

    foreach($array as $key=>$val) {
        if($key===$before_key) {
            $new_array[key($add)] = $add[key($add)];
        }
        $new_array[$key] = $val;
    }
    $array = $new_array;
    var_dump($array);
```

Comment: In wordpress, I have to add content between two specific paragraphs. So I have already split the content into paragraphs and have already identified where the extra content should go. It is just a matter now of adding that content :-). Will test your solution this afternoon. +1 for your solution. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the original array can be associative...

```
$ar = array
(
    '0' => 'value 0',
    '1' => 'value 1',
    '2' => 'value 2',
    '3' => 'value 3',
);

var_dump(insertAfter($ar, '1', array('a' => 'a')));

function insertAfter($arr, $key, $piece)
{
   $keys = array_keys($arr);
   $index = array_search($key, $keys);
   if ($index !== false)
      $ar = array_merge(
            array_slice($arr, 0, $index + 1, true),
            $piece, 
            array_slice($arr, $index + 1, null, true));
   return $ar;
 }
```

Result:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(7) "value 0"
  [1]=>
  string(7) "value 1"
  ["a"]=>
  string(1) "a"
  [2]=>
  string(7) "value 2"
  [3]=>
  string(7) "value 3"
}
```

ps: fixed for the keys, but if there is no need in keys preservation then

```
function insertAfter($arr, $key, $piece)
{
   $before = array();
   $keys = array_keys($arr);
   $index = array_search($key, $keys);
   if ($index !== false)
       $before = array_splice($arr, 0, $index + 1, $piece);
   return array_merge($before, $arr);
}
```

Comment: Will test this afternoon. +1 for your approach

Comment: It lost the key, will fix it )

Comment: No, that is perfect, leave as is. This will save me actually, because I would have needed to reset the keys back to numerical value

Comment: @PieterGoosen Fixed it, keys are preserved

Comment: I can't unfortunately roll back your change, but you original approach was perfect. Mind rolling back your change. My idea was to reset the keys after I have inserted the new key/value pair.

Comment: @PieterGoosen I kept it too.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my pseudocode of my approach (this is written in python but the concept is still there)

```
for key, item in enumerate(array):
  if key == 2:
     thirdKey = array[key]
     array[1] = a
  if key == 3:
     fourthKey = array[key]
     array[2] = thirdKey
  if key == 4:
     array[3] = fourthKey
```

Kind of a long approach but I hope it helps :)

Comment: Ya, it is quite long. And the array is always never the same lengh, it can have 3 key/value pairs or 50